# If $a^2+b^2>c^2+d^2$ where, $a,b,c,d>0$ then can we say that $a+b>c+d$

Tags: inequality

I need to find that if $a^2+b^2>c^2+d^2$ where $a,b,c,d>0$ then $a+b>c+d$. How can I prove if it's true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true:
$$
7^2+1^2\gt5^2+4^2\\
7+1\lt5+4
$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

NO. Take $c=d=1, a=\sqrt 2$ and $ b=\epsilon$ where $0 <\epsilon <2-\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Consider, for instance, the counterexample
$$
6^2+1^2>4^2+4^2
$$
where
$$
6+1<4+4
$$